# Calling via webrtc in safari doesn't work

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc

I'm trying to create web app which communicates via **SIP** protocol on **PBX asterisk**. I'm also using jquery library **[sipjs.com](http://www.sipjs.com)**. In all browsers calling via **webrtc** works, except of safari.

Is there a chance that safari doesn't support calling via **webrtc**? If not, is there a way how to do it possible for safari?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com - no. See http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/heres-make-internet-explorer-safari-work-webrtc/ for a workaround but it requires a Safari extension.

Comment: Safari and Internet Explorer do not support WebRTC at the present time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- safari does not support Webrtc natively.
- there are ongoing efforts like webrtcinwebkit.org to make it happen, but it will take time.
- There is a way to make safari on desktop support Webrtc by using e.g the Temasys free plugin.
- there is no way to make iOS Safari or debit framework support Webrtc.

Comment: i tried installing the plugin (temasys)but still not working not on safari or edge ,but it worked in IE !!!!!!! how is that and is there is another way to make webrtc work on safari

Comment: you should ask temasys about it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/temasys-discuss-webrtcplugin

Comment: The Temasys plugin certainly supports Safari on OSX. There were some issues with it under Safari 9 on Mavericks and Yosemite that were corrected in the most recent release. The team at support.temasys.com.sg would be happy to help you get it up and running if you don't have luck with the latest release